# Javascript: Div is opening but not collapsing back

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this div that I have created. I want it to expand when a link is clicked and collapse when it is clicked again.  It seems to expand the div correctly but does not collapse it. Please help

```
<script>

        function setDisplay()
        {
            document.getElementById('divCollapse').style.display="none";
        }

        function expandSelected()
        {
            if(document.getElementById('divCollapse').style.display="none")
            {document.getElementById('divCollapse').style.display="block";}

            else if(document.getElementById('divCollapse').style.display="block")
            {document.getElementById('divCollapse').style.display="none";}

        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to use `==` for the comparisons in your `if/else if` blocks.  right now you are using `=` which is setting the display, not checking it.

```
<script>

    function setDisplay()
    {
        document.getElementById('divCollapse').style.display="none";
    }

    function expandSelected()
    {
        if(document.getElementById('divCollapse').style.display=="none")
        {document.getElementById('divCollapse').style.display="block";}

        else if(document.getElementById('divCollapse').style.display=="block")
        {document.getElementById('divCollapse').style.display="none";}

    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank so much! It works like a charm! can you also plese comment on how could I add a transition to the same code so it expands in a more graceful way, rather than abruptly?

Comment: your welcome, adding a transition is out of the scope of this question, but it will probably be easiest to use CSS3 transitions on the `height` of the div.  check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331353/transitions-on-the-display-property) and [this reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions) to learn more about CSS3 transistions, if you are still having issues id suggest to ask another question with your updated code and any errors/issues you are getting with the transitions.

Answer (score 3):

`=` is an assignment operator.

Use `==` for comparing values.

So Try

```
function expandSelected() {
   if(document.getElementById('divCollapse').style.display == "none") { // See here
      document.getElementById('divCollapse').style.display = "block";
   } else if(document.getElementById('divCollapse').style.display == "block") { // See here
      document.getElementById('divCollapse').style.display = "none";
   }

}
```

Have a look at [comparison operators.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Comparison_operators)